# How to wrap text on background image with css

Tags: html, css

I want to locate sidebar on to the background image. But following code gives me the sidebar below the image. How can I solve it?

```
<div class="image_container_1"> 
<img src="assets/images/wallpaper1.jpg" alt="wallpaper1" no-repeat center center fixed height="50%">
    <div class="sidebar" style="position: absolute" >
        <ul>
            <li>news</li>
            <li>ratings</li>   
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Folowing is the css code.

```
.image_container_1{
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        filter: opacity(0.7);
}

.sidebar{
        position: fixed;
        width: 30%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: no-repeat center center fixed height="50%"  what it is? It's not how img tag works

Comment: you are confusing background-image and `<img>` tag here, use one or the other. (according to your description `background-image` will work better for your situation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set sidebar on the image you can set sidebar css `position:absolute` and image css `position:fixed`.

```css
.image_container_1{
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        filter: opacity(0.7);
}

.sidebar{
        position: absolute;
}

#banner{
  position:fixed;
  height:80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_container_1"> 
<img src="https://ihud.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/banner-png-3.png" alt="wallpaper1" id="banner">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>news</li>
            <li>ratings</li>   
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```